# integer expression expected - shell scripting

Tags: shell, scripting

The source code is :

```
#!/bin/bash

read nr

if [ $nr -le 2 ]
then
        echo " $nr is not prime"
else
        d=2
        while [ $d -le `expr $nr / 2 ` ] && [ `expr $d % $nr ` -ne 0 ]
        do
                d=$((d+1))
        done
        if [ $d -le `expr $nr/2 ` ]
        then
                echo " $nr is not prime"
        else
                echo " $nr is prime"
        fi
fi
```

If for example the "nr" variable has the value 6, I get the error :

```
./prim.sh: line 14: [: 6/2: integer expression expected
```

Comment: If you're using `$((…))`, you shouldn't need to use `expr` at all; `expr` is relatively clumsy.  It's also better to use `$(…)` rather than back-ticks in general.  You could also read up on the `[[` built-in — I don't like it, but I'm weird and ancient (and it offends my antique sensibilities about consistency of notation).

Answer (score 0):

```
[ 2 -le 6/2 ] && echo yes
```

will not work, but

```
[ 2 -le $(( 6/2 )) ] && echo yes
```

should.

Answer (score 0):

```
# the source of problem is that `expr $nr/2 ` is different of `expr $nr / 2 ` ( with space arround the "/" caracter):
# if nr=6
# `expr $nr/2 ` is a string "6/2"
# `expr $nr / 2 ` is 3

nr=6
echo `expr $nr/2 `
#6/2

echo `expr $nr / 2 `
#3

if [ $d -le `expr $nr/2 ` ]
# will compare an integer with a string 

# contrariwise, the following statement is ok :
if [ $d -le `expr $nr / 2` ]
```

there is another problem about the modulo  : ( $nr % $d ) and not ( $d % $nr )

## Correction :

```
#!/bin/bash

read nr

if [ $nr -le 2 ]
then
        echo "$nr is prime"
else
        d=2
        while [ $d -le `expr $nr / 2 ` ] && [ `expr $nr % $d ` -ne 0 ]
        do
                d=$((d+1))
        done
        if [ $d -le `expr $nr / 2` ]
        then
                echo "$nr is not prime"
        else
                echo "$nr is prime"
        fi
fi
done
```

## Check

```
for nr in {1..12}; do 
d=2
if [ $nr -le 2 ]
then
        echo "$nr is prime"
else
        d=2
        while [ $d -le `expr $nr / 2 ` ] && [ `expr $nr % $d ` -ne 0 ]
        do
                d=$((d+1))
        done
        if [ $d -le `expr $nr / 2` ]
        then
                echo "$nr is not prime"
        else
                echo "$nr is prime"
        fi
fi
done

#1 is prime
#2 is prime
#3 is prime
#4 is not prime
#5 is prime
#6 is not prime
#7 is prime
#8 is not prime
#9 is not prime
#10 is not prime
#11 is prime
#12 is not prime
```